# How to get inner html in wrapper html

Tags: css, html, innerhtml

**EDIT [SCREENSHOT](http://postimg.org/image/fewz60ozp/)**

I want to create a portfolio page. My problem is the inner html

```
    <div class="box desktop-3 tablet-3 tablet-ls-3 mobile-3">
                <a class="modulText" href='#module'>
                    <img src="../img/placeholder.png" />
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="label-text">
                            <div class="text-title">
                               <%= title %>
                            </div>
                            <span class="text-category">Category</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
        </div>
```

the css looks like this:

```
desktop-3 {
   width: 25%;
}

.box {
   min-height: 282px;
   padding: 10px;
   float: left;
}

img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
   z-index: 1;
}

.label {
    background-color: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.label-text {
    color:#fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index:500;
    padding:5px 8px;
}

text-category {
    display: block;
    font-size: 9px;
}
```

as soon as the `text-title` doesn't fit in one box the `label` height changes and i'm not able to show 4 boxes in one row. I just want to have the `label` in the `box` element fiexed. If the `text-title` is to wide i want to have the whole label getting higher inside the `box` not that the box is getting higher. [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tqJCL/)

thanks for an advice

Comment: @Adarsh you can see the link to the screenshot above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot, I understood that the second title is longer. That breaks the layout. So you might want to add the below CSS to `text-title` avoid design breakage. The below code will keeps the title in one line.

```
.text-title {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
width: 400px;
}
```